# Install Windows7 into Bootcamp (using mid-2011 iMac)

Tags: bootcamp, windows, disk-utility

I am having a hard time getting Windows 7 to install on my iMac 2011. Any help would be most appreciated. 
There seems to be a lot of different ways to get this to work depending on various system specs etc so I am getting confused trying to get the correct method to work on my particular machine.

***My iMac specs***:
21.5inch mid 2001, macOS High Sierra, Bootcamp version 6.1.0,
and a brand new 16gb blank USB Stick (formatted to MS-DOS Fat using Disk Utility erase feature, blank DVD-RW)

Here is what I have tried so far:

---

**Method 1**

- Downloaded ISO Windows 7 Pro file
- Formatted MS-DOS FAT 16GB 2.0 USB Stick using Disk Utility
- Inserted blank DVD
- Right click ISO file > Open With > DiskImageMounter
- Disk Utility > Right click mounted iso file
- File > New Image > Format > DVD/CD Master > Save file
- Rename new file from .cdr to .iso
- Right click > Open With > DiskImageMounter
- Run Bootcamp (both boxes checked)
  -- Download latest Windows support software
  -- Install Windows 7

Bootcamp gives me this message:

*The installer disc could not be found.
Insert your Windows installer disc and wait a few seconds for the disc to be recognized.*

---

**Method 2**

- Downloaded ISO Windows 7 Pro file
- Formatted MS-DOS FAT 16GB 2.0 USB Stick using Disk Utility
- Inserted blank DVD
- Right click ISO file > Open With > DiskImageMounter
- Disk Utility > Right click mounted iso file
- File > New Image > Format > DVD/CD Master > Save file
- Keep file as .cdr
- Right click > Open With > DiskImageMounter
- Run Bootcamp (both boxes checked)
  -- Download latest Windows support software
  -- Install Windows 7

Bootcamp gives me this message:

### *The installer disc could not be found. Insert your Windows installer disc and wait a few seconds for the disc to be recognized.*

Comment: Are you sure your DVD is being recognized?

Answer (score 1):

You have not burned the Windows 7 ISO file to the DVD-RW. For example, I have the Windows 7 ISO file named `English_Windows_7_Professional_SP1_W64_X17-59186.iso`. To burn to a DVD-RW, I would need to right click on the file in the Finder application and select `Burn Disk Image "English_Windows_7_Professional_SP1_W64_X17-59186.iso" to Disk...`, as shown below.

[image: p2]

> Note: The Windows 7 ISO is required to include Service Pack 1 (SP1). See the website, [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016), for more information.

Just so you know, 64 bit Windows 10 runs great on your model Mac. I know this to be true because I also have a iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011).